# Namespacing in terms of static declarations and the call

Tags: javascript, namespaces

I have the following code: http://jsfiddle.net/pepNU/1/

I want to make a static reference to "YourGame" and indeed the "Settings" inside it, so the only way I could think of doing this was add it as a private variable(class if you will) and then reference it as a variable in the return of YourGame, thus it could be called like:

```
YourGame.Settings.GetFrameRate();
```

What are your thoughts on this? Should I be doing something more like this to namespace:

```
YourGame.Settings = function...
```

I obviously cannot just plonk the function inside the return as I then cannot get to the GetFrameRate() function returning within the Settings with a simple call like the aforementioned

Answer (score 0):

What you did is fine, but since you just need a single instance and there is no constructor logic, you could also have used an object literal:

```
var YourGame = {
    Settings : {
        // ...
    },
    // ...
}
```

If you need an instantiable "class" with "static" properties, you can also add properties to the constructor directly:

```
var YourGame = function() {
   // constructor logic
}
YourGame.foo = 10; // static property
var game = new YourGame; // instance
game.foo; // undefined
YourGame.foo; // 10
```

Comment: If in the future I need to make an insatiable object, I am screwed. You're right though, this is certainly an option. interesting.

Comment: I just realised, this will also make it quite difficult to use client and server pattern development. (returning private declarations in public scope functions)... hmm.

Comment: If anything, this is pretty much the answer I was hoping for. "What you did is fine". the external namespacing was one of the options I tried out, I wonder what the downsides are of this. Perhaps it's even clearer to read.. argh, I hate having so many options! Let me see if anyone else has something to say about this, if not, ill mark you down as the answer.